# java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException:Keyspace names must be composed of alphanumerics and underscores (parsed: '')

Tags: java, database, eclipse, hadoop, cassandra

I'm trying connect to cassandra db and verify users to login and sign up I'm getting this error:

```
Keyspace names must be composed of alphanumerics and underscores (parsed: '')
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.Utils.parseURL(Utils.java:195)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver.connect(CassandraDriver.java:85)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at com.rest.inndata.services.ConnectCassandra.createConnection(ConnectCassandra.java:56)
    at com.rest.inndata.services.callGoad.checkUser(callGoad.java:1123)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1480)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1411)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1360)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1350)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)    
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
```

Comment: This says: Whatever you are passing to `parseURL` should not be an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removed all spaces while creating a keyspace.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted in your answer, you cannot have spaces in your keyspace name:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> CREATE TABLE "testorder by" (id uuid PRIMARY KEY, value text);
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message=""testorder by" is not a valid column 
    family name (must be alphanumeric character only: [0-9A-Za-z]+)"
```

And although it doesn't explicitly indicate spaces, the documentation has this to say:

> Keyspace names are 32 or fewer alpha-numeric characters and underscores, the first of which is an alpha character. Keyspace names are case-insensitive. To make a name case-sensitive, enclose it in double quotation marks.

Honestly, the error message does a better job of indicating the valid characters with the regex.